# Spring integration inbound email adapter

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Can I reject emails based on sender email id using the mail-filter-expression attribute in the IMAP inbound adapter

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by "reject", you mean simply ignore, then yes, from the `AbstractMailReceiver`...

```
if (this.selectorExpression.getValue(this.evaluationContext, message, Boolean.class)) {
    filteredMessages.add(message);
}
else {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()){
        logger.debug("Fetched email with subject '" + message.getSubject() + "' will be discarded by the matching filter" +
                        " and will not be flagged as SEEN.");
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The `#root` object of the expression is a `MimeMessage`; `getFrom()` returns an `Address[]` so something like

```
"from == null || from.length == 0 ? false : from[0].toString().contains('something.org') ? true : false"
```

should work.

For something more complex, you could write a Java class, define it as a bean, and reference it from the expression: `"@myMailFilter.filter(#root)"`.

EDIT2:

Note that, if using IMAP you can also use a `search-term-strategy` to limit the emails that are even considered (retrieved).

For example:

```
@Override
public SearchTerm generateSearchTerm(Flags supportedFlags, Folder folder) {
    try {
        return new FromTerm(new InternetAddress("*@something.org"));
    }
    catch (AddressException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gary . I meant ignore . I was looking to see if it is possible to write an spel expression on the mail-filter-expression attribute to accept emails from say @something.org

Comment: Sorry; misread your requirement; reversed the expression logic.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Is there a AbstractMailFilter available like the AbstractFileListFilter

Comment: No; in this case, the filter is a simple `expression` that must return a boolean, so any `POJO` method that returns a boolean is all that's needed.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I tried using a simple bean with a method that returns a boolean earlier. I got the exceptions... -> Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1057E:(pos 1): No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'beanname'
I am working with spring 3.1.3 and spring integration 2.2.0 in this project.

Comment: Ah; yes, we made some improvements in Spring Integration 3.0 to allow bean references (`@beanName`) in all expressions throughout the framework. Prior to that, some expressions (like this one) could not reference beans. One solution for 2.2.x would be to use a `static` method on a class that returns a boolean (instead of a bean), and invoke it with `T(foo.MyMailFilter).filter(#root)` (the `T()` operator in SpEL resolves to the class, so you can then invoke a static method on it). I would also recommend you at least upgrade to the latest 2.2.x release (2.2.6).

Comment: I upgraded SI to 3.0.4 . Spring version is 3.1.3 . I do not get the abover error . but now I see a NOSuchBeandefinition .I have the bean annotated as Component and the package is component scanned at startup. I see Caused by: org.springframework.expression.AccessException: Could not resolve bean reference against BeanFactory and Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'EmailFilter' is defined
Do I need to increase version of Spring also

Comment: Spring should be OK; turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework` and monitor the bean creation messages. The bean name will be camelCased `emailFilter`.

Comment: ok thanks. I gave an explicit beanname  in the annotation and it works. but now the poller seems to running in loop trying to fetch same email repeatedly .I have should-mark-messages-as-read="true" set in the inbound adapter. Will it remain unread if the mail-filter-expresson evaluates to false always.

Comment: Btw - I would expect component-scan to work and instantiate the bean and make it available via the beanfactory .Not sure what caused the above nosuchbeandefinition error

Comment: Mails that pass the filter should be marked as read; mails that do not (false) are left as unread. If you want them marked as 'seen' you should use a `<filter expression="..." />` downstream of the adapter instead.

Comment: "I would expect..."... It does, but if the class name is `foo.EmailFilter`, the bean name is `emailFilter`, by default.

Comment: Gary ,do you mean I should  use a seperate <filter > instead of the the mail-filter-expression

Comment: Yes, if you want the ignored message to be marked as seen.

Comment: Ok thanks for your insights . I got it working . I wasn't able to reference the bean directly in the expression attribute . I just defined ref and method as usual and got it working

Comment: Does this mean then - mail-filter-expression cannot be used by itself if it evaluates to false , in an inbound adapter , without actually flagging an email as SEEN in some other way

Comment: It depends on your mail provider - providers that support `\Recent` don't need to be marked as seen. For example, [Gmail doesn't support recent](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78761?hl=en&topic=1668982&ctx=topic). I have opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3498) to add an option to mark filtered messages as seen.